# Is there a way to audit every DML Events without writing triggers to each table?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Is there a way where I can audit every tables changes without writing each triggers for every table.

I have nearly   nearly 500 tables and writing triggers for each of them is very hectic task and managing them is a nightmare.

Furthermore most of the tables are normalized which makes the things that I need track more complicated.

However every insert,update,delete,select task is done through stored procedures.
One of the solution is auditing through those procedures . However I am looking to  an effortless Solution for auditing. Some sort like server level triggers on every stored procedure which tracks every tables that is being used on the procedure

Comment: Generate Triggers for all Tables dynamically like this: http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/brettk/archive/2006/11/29/35816.aspx

Comment: you can use extended events as well

Comment: SQL2016+: see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/temporal-tables

Answer (score 0):

If you are on Enterprise Edition and @@version >= 2008 you can use **database audit**.

Here you can find an example of setting it [SQL Server 2008 Auditing Feature](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1954/sql-server-2008-auditing-feature/)

And here you find the official doc [Create a Server Audit and Database Audit Specification](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/auditing/create-a-server-audit-and-database-audit-specification)